# Conflicts between existing/new data keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Attaching data to elements in jQuery is easy:

`$(selector).data(key, value)`.

However, it occurred to me that I may want to prefix all my keys with my root namespace. For example:

`$(selector).data("MyDotComApp." + key, value)`

Is this a waste of time? Am I overthinking this? Do I need to worry about overwriting any data the core framework writes, or plugins?

Is there a best practice for naming data keys?

Comment: Yea I think you're overthinking it - just use a smart key name that applies to your app. I would assume that jQuery would worry about prefixing their names with something (a token, even) so it doesn't conflict easily. You could always look at jQuery source code too though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly wouldn't hurt, although you wouldn't necessarily need to do it via concatenation of all the various keys.

Whenever you want to create data for your specific domain, you could just create one key in data on the element with the name of your domain, and give it an object that can store the individual keys.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/XwJbQ/

```
  // The myDomain key in data references its own object
$('img').data('myDomain', {});

  // then individual keys are added to the object myDomain references
$('img').data('myDomain').someKey = "some value";
$('img').data('myDomain').someOtherKey = "some other value";

  // and are retrieved the same way
alert( $('img').data('myDomain').someKey );
alert( $('img').data('myDomain').someOtherKey );
```